# How do I change the categorical rows to columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

I need some help with respect to changing a dataframe in python.

```
     NODE      SIGNAL-STRENGTH   LOCATION 
0   A            76                 1 
1   A            78                 1
2   A            78                 1
3   A            79                 1
4   A            79                 2
5   A            70                 2
.
.
.
95  E            111                 4
96  E            123                 5
97  E            154                 5
98  E            113                 5
99  E            234                 5
```

The above data is a dataframe where there are 5 nodes each with 20 data points which are 5 locations that each send 4 signal strength values to each node. For each node I have 4 signal strength values from a location and the location itself. The location is the label and the signal strength changes for different nodes for different nodes.

I wish to have only 20 rows, with 6 columns. One of the columns will be location. the other five must be the nodes and have the signal strength for that location.

The location order does not change after 20 rows. This means that the 20 locations are in order after the end of each node.

I tried to do groupby but I don't know how to change it to rows.

Final dataframe must be as

```
   LOCATION    NODEA_SIGNAL       NODE_B_SIGNAL    NODE_C_SIGNAL   NODE_D_SIGNAL NODE_E_SIGNAL
0   1            76                 34                 55              44           64
1   1            77                 33                 55              45           65
2   1            77                 33                 54              43           66
3   1            78                 31                 53              45           67
4   2            34                 42                 94              85           12
5   2            37                 44                 98              82           13
6   2            36                 45                 97              83           14
7   2            35                 44                 96              86           16
8   3            23                 16                 47              65           85
.
.
.
15  4            16                 24                 64              95           75
16  5            46                 74                 15              54           34
17  5            47                 73                 15              55           35
18  5            47                 73                 14              53           36
19  5            48                 71                 13              55           37
```

Answer (score 1):

Setup

```py
data = {
    "NODE": [chr(j) for j in range(65, 65+5) for _ in range(j, j+20)],
    "SIGNAL-STRENGTH": np.random.randint(75, 200, 100),
    "LOCATION": np.arange(100) % 5 + 1
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.sort_values(by=["NODE", 'LOCATION'], inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Only thing that i dont know is how to get length of `LOCATION`, when there is more rows:

```
data_new = {"LOCATION": [i//4 + 1 for i in range(20)]}
```

Main body:

```
out_df = pd.DataFrame(data_new)
for n, sub_df in df.groupby("NODE")["SIGNAL-STRENGTH"]:
    name = f"NODE_{n}_SIGNAL"
    out_df[name] = sub_df.reset_index(drop=True)
out_df.to_markdown()
```

```
|    |   LOCATION |   NODE_A_SIGNAL |   NODE_B_SIGNAL |   NODE_C_SIGNAL |   NODE_D_SIGNAL |   NODE_E_SIGNAL |
|---:|-----------:|----------------:|----------------:|----------------:|----------------:|----------------:|
|  0 |          1 |             161 |             109 |              90 |             138 |             185 |
|  1 |          1 |              95 |              76 |             100 |             157 |              95 |
|  2 |          1 |             113 |             107 |             140 |             195 |             188 |
|  3 |          1 |             191 |             117 |             180 |             152 |              97 |
|  4 |          2 |             196 |              97 |             119 |             176 |             107 |
|  5 |          2 |             181 |             134 |             196 |             103 |             115 |
|  6 |          2 |             160 |             138 |             110 |              79 |             165 |
|  7 |          2 |             143 |              77 |             179 |             183 |             143 |
|  8 |          3 |             127 |             139 |             198 |              95 |             151 |
|  9 |          3 |             124 |             150 |             129 |             155 |             155 |
| 10 |          3 |             147 |             126 |             110 |             131 |              92 |
| 11 |          3 |              77 |             171 |             154 |             190 |             109 |
| 12 |          4 |             156 |             154 |             133 |              89 |             163 |
| 13 |          4 |              81 |             185 |             131 |             192 |              93 |
| 14 |          4 |             144 |             140 |             124 |             131 |             151 |
| 15 |          4 |             199 |             162 |             162 |             146 |             112 |
| 16 |          5 |              80 |              89 |              94 |             147 |             190 |
| 17 |          5 |             188 |             110 |             126 |             147 |             108 |
| 18 |          5 |             125 |             163 |             159 |             108 |             186 |
| 19 |          5 |             140 |             106 |             124 |             174 |              77 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html#pandas-pivot-table):

```py
df = (
    df.pivot_table(index="LOCATION", columns="NODE", values="SIGNAL-STRENGTH")
    .add_prefix("NODE_")
    .add_suffix("_SIGNAL")
    .reset_index()
)
df.columns.name = None
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   LOCATION  NODE_A_SIGNAL  NODE_B_SIGNAL  NODE_C_SIGNAL  NODE_D_SIGNAL  NODE_E_SIGNAL
0         1             76             78             79            111            154
1         2             78             79             70            123            113
```

---

Data used:

```
  NODE  SIGNAL-STRENGTH  LOCATION
0    A               76         1
1    A               78         2
2    B               78         1
3    B               79         2
4    C               79         1
5    C               70         2
6    D              111         1
7    D              123         2
8    E              154         1
9    E              113         2
```